# How to get roslyn to compile when referenced assemblies have references to both mscorlib 2.0.5.0 and 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm dynamically building a class that uses Microsoft.OData.Client this library have references to both mscorlib 2.0.5.0 (i guess the PCL) and 4.0.0.0.
[image]

I want to compile my class with roslyn, as part of a larger program, but I can't seem to get it to work. My Roslyn compiler code is pretty minimalistic

```
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(s);
            string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            List<MetadataReference> references = new List<MetadataReference>()
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DataServiceActionQuery).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ODataAction).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(GeneratedCodeAttribute).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(IEdmModel).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(TimeOfDay).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(XmlDocument).Assembly.Location),
               // MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile328\mscorlib.dll")

            };

            references.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades").Select(f => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(f)));

            var op = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
            //op.WithAssemblyIdentityComparer(DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default);
            //CSharpCompilationOptions.WithAssemblyIdentityComparer(DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default);
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName,
                syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
                references: references,
                options: op);
            Assembly assembly = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        //diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());                 
                }
        }
```

These are the errors I get

> CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
>
> CS0012: The type 'XmlReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

Comment: Have you tried adding an assembly redirect for those assemblies to your app.config? (And by extension to the *.exe.config)

Comment: I cant get assembly redirect to do anything - also don't think that is the problem here. The problem is most likely how i setup the roslyn compiler.

Comment: IIRC `DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer` solved the issue for me once. Note however, that `CSharpCompilationOptions` is immutable as well... have you tried `op = op.WithAssemblyIdentityComparer(DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default)`?

Comment: OMG @m0sa I'm such a tool, it is working now with your suggestion. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you predicted in the comments `DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer` is the solution. However, `CSharpCompilationOptions` is immutable, and the `WithAssemblyIdentityComparer` method returns a new instance, so you have to use it like this:

```
var op = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
op = op.WithAssemblyIdentityComparer(DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default);
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    assemblyName,
    syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
    references: references,
    options: op);
```